# Reading .bundle files in Cocoa Application

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, plugins, bundle

I am creating a cocoa web browser using WKWebView and Swift. Like most browsers, they have extensions or plugins. I want to implement the same thing in my web browser. I came across CFPlugin. I want to use this feature but I do not know how. It would be good if you give a sample application.

I haven't tried anything because I don't know what to do

This is how I want my extension to look like

```
myExtension.bundle/
      info.plist
      scripts1.js
      popoverview.xib
      popoverview.swift
      script2.js
      popuppage.html
      image.png
      popuppage.css
```

I want to know how to read the files in the bundle

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After a few minutes of trying I found the answer

Bundles are considered as Directories

so you can do something like this

`MyBundle.bundle/Contents/Info.plist`

`MyBundle.bundle/Contents/Resources/MyView.xib`